# Does decryptor need to know initialization vector?

Tags: security, ssl, aes, cbc-mode

Trying to understand how encrytion works in specific application I use. I know that system transfer  16 bytes long AES-128 key to other side and its value in hex is `2b779fddc83888c18253f14022497328`. I also know that `AES CBC` algorithm is used for encryption. Data for encryption is string `aaaaaaaa`.

Trying to reproduce encrypt with `openssl enc` command:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -K 2b779fddc83888c18253f14022497328 -iv 0123456789ABCDEF -in plain.txt -out encrypted.txt
```

According this procedure I found that initialization vector is also needed, but application documentation says nothing about it. Is it possible that `IV` omitted in application? Does usual way of passing key to other side includes initialization vector also?

Content of `encrypted.txt`in case `aaaaaaaa` input string:

```
48 EF 03 13 71 AE 2F DC │ 54 99 4D F6 F5 F1 ED 60
```

UPD

I found in documentation that my 8 bytes input string should be trailed with NUL till length becomes 16 bytes.

In this case content of `plain.txt` in HEX is:

```
61 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

and content of `encrypted.txt`:

```
3E 12 7D 26 60 EF E4 AD 34 D8 94 11 27 28 59 E8 F6 D8 5F 4B D1 03 69 A5 13 09 FC BD 49 A9 EF 8C
```

Does knowing that last 8 bytes in plain.txt is always NUL brings information to decryptor about IV?

Comment: Its not very clear what you are actually asking here. The initialization vector is usually provided with the cyphertext.

Comment: CBC mandatory uses an IV, i.e. the applicationm must apply an IV somewhere  (if really CBC is used). Preferably poste the encryption code. At least, share the ciphertext that the application generates with the posted plaintext and key.

Comment: I have updated question body with content of encrypted.txt

Comment: I found that text to be encrypted should be padded with 8 items of NUL? Does knowing that in other side brings information about IV? More details in UPD in question body.

Comment: Both ciphertexts can be decrypted with the IV `0x0123456789abcdef0000000000000000`. The decryption also shows that PKCS#7 padding was used.

Answer (score 1):

With CBC-based AES encryption, the IV must be chosen randomly and is a public information. It makes two encrypted contents of the same byte array not having the same encrypted value. You need to know the IV value to decrypt the data.